# Remove all attributes from an element using Java

Tags: java, dom, attributes

I need to remove all attributes from a particular element in a Document.

How I have the xml :

```
    <Book>
     <Chapter TotalNoOfWords="2000" NoOfPages="5">
       <Line LineNo="1" NumberOfWords="50"/>
     </Chapter>
    </Book>
```

How I need it to be :

```
    <Book>
     <Chapter>
      <Line LineNo="1" NumberOfWords="50"/>
     </Chapter>
    </Book>
```

I am aware of the removeAttribute() method. But this method will only remove the attribute for which the name has been passed as an argument to this method. I am looking for something that will remove all attributes in the element.
Any help on this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you already have the specified `Node` element, loop through all the elements and remove them...

```
while (node.getAttributes().getLength() > 0) {
    Node att = node.getAttributes().item(0);
    node.getAttributes().removeNamedItem(att.getNodeName());
}
```

For example...